# Symmetric cross join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm tryng to extract all pair say `i,j` from each element in a table against each element on the same table, here my query:

```
select a.Id L,b.id R into #cross from MyTable a cross join mytable b
```

I'm in the situation where `i,j == j,i` so just half the record are needed. My naive attempt is:

```
select a.Id L,b.id R into #cross from MyTable a cross join mytable b 
where not exists
    (select * from #cross c where c.L=R and c.R=L)
```

but I can't query the destination table while inserting in, as said by SQL Server:

```
The SELECT INTO statement cannot have same source and destination tables
```

how can I do in an efficient way ?

**EDIT**
Just for reference, I said "I need half the records", that is wrong, the record count after taking in account that `i,j == j,i` is `n*(n+1)/2`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, just condition the join so that the left side is always equal to or lesser!

```
    select a.Id L,b.id R
      into #cross
      from MyTable a
inner join mytable b on a.id <= b.id
```

Comment: To get the correct result, a.id should be less than b.id, and the equal sign should not be used in the join condition.