# Cross Join without duplicate combinations

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I know this question is very similar to this one:
[Symmetric cross join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12490244/symmetric-cross-join)
and this one too:
[combinations (not permutations) from cross join in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7112513/combinations-not-permutations-from-cross-join-in-sql)

But what about if we have two different tables, say A and B:

```
select A.id,B.id from A cross join B
```

and I want to consider the pair `(a,b)` equal to `(b,a)` ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
select A.id aid,B.id bid
from A inner join B on a.id <= b.id
union
select B.id,A.id
from A inner join B on b.id < a.id
```

If you wanted to be more sophisticated:

```
select distinct
       case when a.id<=b.id then a.id else b.id end id1,
       case when a.id<=b.id then b.id else a.id end id2
from A cross join B
```

In my little unscientific bake off with tiny tables, the latter was faster.  And below, the `case` expressions written as subqueries.

```
select distinct
       (select MIN(id) from (select a.id union select b.id)[ ]) id1,
       (select MAX(id) from (select a.id union select b.id)[ ]) id2
from A cross join B
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be a `<=` in one of the conditions?

Comment: +1 except one of the joins should include `a = b`, ie `a.id <= b.id`

Comment: Great solution, I use the first since it is more clear and i have not so many records, it would be interesting to have the rule for the count

Comment: The conditions in both cases are the same.

Comment: @QMaster yes I thought that was wrong at first too, but the "then" part of the clause switches the result which makes the query correct.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this give the desired result as well?

```
select A.id,B.id from A cross join B on A.id >= B.id
```

Comment: No, because as far as I know, CROSS JOINs can not have a joining condition