# select all from multiple tables in a ordered way without duplicate rows

Tags: php, mysql

I've been looking for this but I didn't found what I need. I'm creating an admin page and I need to access the db values from a php interface.

I need to get all the rows from many tables. First I tried with:

```
SELECT * FROM t1, t2, t3, t4
```

But that's duplicating rows many times, something odd... The first table have 8 rows, the second 8 too, the third 7 and the fourth 1. There are 24 rows in total, but if I execute that query I get 448 rows... why?

Let's say that I have 4 tables and I want to get all that data in one query, get the columns in the order I put the tables in the query but without duplicate... There are no conditions, just get all the data like if I make 4 queries:

```
SELECT * FROM t1
SELECT * FROM t2
SELECT * FROM t3
SELECT * FROM t4
```

If I do this no data is duplicated... why?

How would I merge those 4 queries but still getting the same results? (no duplicated data)

Comment: `SELECT * FROM t1, t2, t3, t4` creates implicit `JOIN' between the 4 tables. Since you apply no filters it translates to Cartesian Product of the four.

Comment: If all tables have the same structure, use [`UNION`](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/union.php).

Comment: Ah right, I figured that something like that was happening but I never heard of the Carteasian Product. No, they are different tables. I could just make 4 queries but I'd like to know how can I do this.

Comment: Why doesn't `UNION` do what you want?

Comment: You're executing a `cross join`. Don't do that! - http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/advance-query-in-mysql/mysql-cross-join.php

Comment: Think about the column names in each table. If they're different, what can you expect the results to be when you query all four of them; how could you retrieve the values from the result set?

Comment: @miken32 it makes sense if the tables are joining... so is there any way to select the data without joining the tables?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross Join without duplicate combinations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12932045/cross-join-without-duplicate-combinations)

Comment: But in a join, the fields in each row of the result set are related in some way. There's no relation here. You have to have four queries. What's the problem with four queries?

Comment: No problem at all, I just thought I could get the data in 1 query. I'll make as many as I'll need.

Answer (score -1):

Like I said in the comment; you're executing a `cross join`. Don't do that!

But in general, if you want to exclude duplicates, you could `SELECT DISTINCT ...`

Comment: Just like that? `SELECT DISTINCT * FROM t1, t2, t3, t4`?

Comment: Hmmm I can still see 448 rows.

Comment: Than they must be different. What is the result of  `SELECT DISTINCT id FROM t1, t2 ...` ?

Comment: Is ok, but because there's only 1 column named id in the 4 tables. The problem is joining them. So now that I know the problem i'd like to know if it's possible to get data from multiple tables without joining them.

Comment: I can't use that since the tables have different columns.

Comment: oh, its late here :) I would fire multiple queries and then merge the result arrays

Comment: Same here. Yeah it's what i'm thinking, make multiple queries. Thanks anyway!