# MySQL : Cannot remove duplicate combination in cross join

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to remove the duplicate combinations from my cross join select statement, I have followed [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12932045/cross-join-without-duplicate-combinations) but the duplicated combination is still there, it even mixes the `credit_id` and `loan_id`. How am I supposed to do this?
My code

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
CASE WHEN `credit`.`id`<=`loan`.`id` THEN `credit`.`id` ELSE `loan`.`id` END AS `credit_id`,
CASE WHEN `credit`.`id`<=`loan`.`id` THEN `loan`.`id` ELSE `credit`.`id` END AS `loan_id`
FROM
(SELECT `id`,`city` as `City with credit`,`fishing_segment` FROM `data` 
WHERE `city` LIKE '%Credit') AS `credit`
CROSS JOIN
(SELECT `id`,`city` as `City with loan`,`fishing_segment` FROM `data` 
WHERE `city` LIKE 'Loan%') AS `loan`;
```

The result

```
+-----------+---------+
| credit_id | loan_id |
+-----------+---------+
|         1 |       2 |
|         2 |       3 |
|         2 |       5 |
|         1 |       4 |
|         3 |       4 |
|         4 |       5 |
|         1 |       6 |
|         3 |       6 |
|         5 |       6 |
+-----------+---------+
```

The result that I want

```
+-----------+---------+
| credit_id | loan_id |
+-----------+---------+
|         1 |       2 |
|         3 |       4 |
|         5 |       6 |
+-----------+---------+
```

Here's the [FIDDLE](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/h1DcmcRAB1UAoLDJcQr9qQ/0)

Comment: *I'm trying to remove the duplicate combinations from my cross join select statement* There is no duplicates in shown output, each final row is unique.

Comment: *The result that I want* Why you store `(1,2)` and remove (1,4) and (1,6)? Define the criteria... maybe you need simpy add `GROUP BY credit_id` and wrap `loan_id` expression into `MIN()` function?

Comment: doing `GROUP BY credit_id` and wrap `loan_id` expression into `MIN()`. Making it showing `credit id` 1,1,1 and `loan_id` 2,4,6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT TRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(city, 'Credit', ''), 'Loan', '')) city,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN LOCATE('Credit', city) THEN id END) credit_ids,
       SUM(CASE WHEN LOCATE('Credit', city) THEN fishing_segment END) credit_fishing_segment,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN LOCATE('Loan', city) THEN id END) loan_ids,
       SUM(CASE WHEN LOCATE('Loan', city) THEN fishing_segment END) loan_fishing_segment
FROM data
GROUP BY 1;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c8c4423d2b9ca8373d85f4fafffe0419)

Comment: Thanks so much @Akina. This really helps me