# C# Linq Query to avoid reversed entries

Tags: linq

Below linq query gives two entries of the same items in nd. Looking for a way to remove the reversed entry.

```
//unit = new List<string>{"F1","F2","F3","F4","F5","F6","F7","F8","F9"}
//v["F3"]="12" v["F6"]="12"

var nd = (from n1 in unit 
          from n2 in unit
          where n1 != n2 && v[n1].Length == 2 && v[n1] == v[n2]
          select new {n1,n2}).ToList();
```

The values in nd is given as below. How can i avoid the 2nd entry?

```
Count = 2
    [0]: { n1 = "F3", n2 = "F6" }
    [1]: { n1 = "F6", n2 = "F3" }
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is extremely trivial. Instead of checking that the two entries are different, check if one is strictly greater than the other:

```
var nd = (from n1 in unit 
          from n2 in unit
          where n1 > n2 && v[n1].Length == 2 && v[n1] == v[n2]
          select new {n1,n2}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could select (n1, n2, min(n1, n2), max(n1, n2)), group by the min and max and select the first in each group.

var result = nd.GroupBy(item => new {item.min, item.max}).Select(grp => new {grp.First().n1, grp.First().n2});

Answer (score -1):

You can compare if one is less than or greater than the other instead of just checking for inequality. The trick is well-known in SQL, for example : [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7112513/combinations-not-permutations-from-cross-join-in-sql), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12490244/symmetric-cross-join).

In .NET LINQ implementation, you can use [`String.CompareOrdinal()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/af26w0wa%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method since comparing strings can't be as straightforward as using `<` or `>` operator :

```
var nd = (from n1 in unit
          from n2 in unit
          where String.CompareOrdinal(n1,n2) < 0 && v[n1].Length == 2 && v[n1] == v[n2]
          select new { n1, n2 }).ToList();
```

Comment: Hmm.. care to explain why the downvote? What am I missing here?